# PHP not comparing with arraypart

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, comparison, file-get-contents

I am creating a simple script which searches through a textfile for the correct combination but it just doesn't work. I troubleshooted everything but all the parts just worked, but still the whole script isn't working and I don't know how to fix it.

code:

```php
<html>

<form>
<input type="text" name="input" placeholder="hash"><button type="submit">Crack!</button>
</form>
<?php
$input = $_GET["input"]; // pulling input from url

$hashes = file_get_contents("hashes.txt"); // loading hashes

$hasharray = explode(";", $hashes); // separating hashcombos

$arraynum = count($hasharray); // counting number of hashcombos

// defining loop
$loopnum = 0;
while($loopnum < $arraynum) {
    $combo = $hasharray[$loopnum]; // selecting hashcombo
    $comboarray = explode("|", $combo); // separating hashcombo
    $text = $comboarray[0];
    $hash = $comboarray[1];

    // cecking if hash matches
    if($hash === $input) {
        echo("Hash: $hash");
        echo("<br>");
        echo("Text: $text");
    }

    $loopnum = $loopnum + 1; // updating loop

}
?>
</html>
```

example hashes.txt:

```
test|example;
example|test;
```

Comment: what error message are you getting?

Comment: There is no error, not mentioned on the website nor in an error log

Comment: Can you share a sample of the file hashes.txt?

Comment: Try to use `$_POST` instead of `$_GET`

Comment: Well you have not provided enough information, what content is in hashes.txt? I would suggest you to do line by line debugging, use `var_dump` method to check if you are getting right data. It seems logical error in your code.

Comment: saulotoledo yes ofcourse

Comment: Aksen P, I changed the form method and the pulling variable to post but still it doesn't work

Comment: I am not sure what is the issue. Changing to POST will not work unless you set the form method to POST in the HTML (the default if you do not inform is GET). Could you describe a test case? (e.g. add "example" to the form and you should expect Y as a result...).

Comment: @HamidAli I debugged every variable with var_dump() but it all seems to be ok, however I did notice there is a space added at the end of every variable and when I try to remove it it doesn't go away

Comment: @Bluppie05 Try this after loading the hashes. I will explain it after your test: `$hashes = preg_replace("/[\r\n]/", "", $hashes);`

Comment: @saulotoledo it works, thank you so much!

Comment: if you make a n answer I will set it on answered so you get the xp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file contains newlines, that are also invisible characters. For example:

```
test|example;(newline here)
example|test;
```

You split the lines in your file by using the `;`, but that does not remove the newline characters. Considering the comments in your question, you have newlines in your results causing your comparisons to fail. That said, I suggest the following solution right after loading the hashes to remove the newline characters:

```php
$hashes = preg_replace("/[\r\n]/", "", $hashes);
```

Which will result in a string like:

```
test|example;example|test;
```

The rest of your code will work as expected.